# API Response Formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I'm working on an exercise to build a quote generator using an API to pull the quotes. My GET request seems to be working just fine, but I'm having trouble manipulating the array that arrives as a response. I'm looking for ideas on how to pull only the Quote Text to one div and only the Character Name (without "quote:" and "character:" attached) into another via jS. Any ideas? I know my javaScript is pretty elementary, I'm just trying to see what I can do.

The API I'm using is at https://github.com/wsizoo/game-of-thrones-quotes. It returns everything as an array, and I'm only logging it to the console right now until I can figure stuff out.

```js
const endPoint = 'https://got-quotes.herokuapp.com/quotes';
const $button = $('#button');
const $quoteDisplay = $('.quoteDisplay');
const $sourceDisplay = $('.sourceDisplay');

function getQuote() {
  $quoteDisplay.empty();
  $sourceDisplay.empty();
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.resposeType = 'json';
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      console.log(xhr.response);
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', endPoint);
  xhr.send();
};

$button.click(getQuote);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GOT Quote Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Game of Thrones Quote Generator</h1>
    <div class="quoteDisplay">
    </div>
    <div class="sourceDisplay">
    </div>
    <button id="button">Get A New Quote</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to create constants for your `$quoteDisplay` and `$sourceDisplay`. Also, the data that you are getting from the API is in `JSON` format, so you need to parse that using `$.parseJSON()` function and then you can use it as normal JavaScript object. Once processed, append the data to your `div` using javascript like below-

```js
const endPoint = 'https://got-quotes.herokuapp.com/quotes';
const $button = $('#button');
const $quoteDisplay = $('.quoteDisplay');
const $sourceDisplay = $('.sourceDisplay');

function getQuote() {
  $quoteDisplay.empty();
  $sourceDisplay.empty();
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.resposeType = 'json';
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      var quote = $.parseJSON(xhr.response);
      $('.list-group').append("<div class='list-group-item'>"+quote.quote+"<br/>"+quote.character+"</div>");
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', endPoint);
  xhr.send();
};

$button.click(getQuote);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GOT Quote Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Game of Thrones Quote Generator</h1>
    <div class="list-group">
    </div>
    <button id="button">Get A New Quote</button>
  </body>
</html>
```